# What utf-8 settings need to be explicitly set in dot emacs

Tags: init-file, utf-8

I run Emacs in Windows via msys2. If I set my language environment in my `.bashrc` using `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` I get as my default environment in Emacs `utf-8-dos`. Is there a need thereafter to set any of the following variables in dot emacs:

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8-dos)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

There seems to me to be some confusion around what utf settings need to be made explicit in dot emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of those are necessary as utf-8 is the default for everything. Furthermore, even if you do want to change the defaults, you should not use the code as you pasted it; it is incomplete. It changes some of the coding system settings, but not all of them. You should instead use `set-language-environment` to set everything at once. See [chapter 23.2 Language Environments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Language-Environments.html) of the Emacs manual for more information.

```lisp
(set-language-environment 'utf-8)
```

But again, even this is unnecessary as utf-8 is the default.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(set-language-environment "UTF-8")`. Double quotes and upper case?

Comment: Yes, technically. However, in practice a symbol will work just as well and the search is not case sensitive.